# Conditional formatting from another conditional format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

In **Sheet X** I have a bunch of cells that are conditionally formatted with a fill color. I want the colors from **Sheet X** to be dynamically updated to **Sheet Y** and **Sheet Z**. That is, if cell `X:3:D` is conditionally formatted to be red, I want cells `Y:3:D` and `Z:3:D` to be red as well. If I change the value in `X:3:D` to cause the cell to be blue, sheets Y and Z should to dynamically update.

Comment: Quite important: Do Y:3:D have the same value as X:3:D?

Comment: @Envite No, and that's the crux of the question. If they did, I could simply copy the conditional formatting rules over to the new sheet. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you willing to have the key *values* replicated onto the other sheets? 
If so, set `SheetY!Q3` to `=SheetX!D3`,
and then have `SheetY!D3` conditionally formatted using the value in `SheetY!Q3`
(but otherwise the same conditional formatting rules as `SheetX!D3`). 
You can hide Column `Q` when you get it working.

Comment: P.S. It’s easier to communicate when you use standard conventions; e.g., `Sheet1!D3` rather than `X:3:D`.

Comment: Thanks for the convention heads up, it's been awhile since I've used Excel. This solution won't work however, I want to place values in a new worksheet but have the colors carry over from a previous one.

Comment: I don’t understand. What do you mean by “a previous” worksheet? A sheet in a different workbook? Yesterday’s values (which no longer exist in the file)?

Comment: Sorry "previous" was a bad choice of words. Given a workbook with three sheets, I want to update a cell in `Sheet1!Q3` which colors it due to conditional formatting from the rules on `Sheet1`. I want that color to be copied to `Sheet2!Q3` and `Sheet3!Q3` but I still want to be able to edit the cell contents of `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`.

Comment: OK, so what’s unworkable about my answer? I’m suggesting that you set up areas on `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` -- maybe out of the way (e.g., Column `Q`, when everything else is in, say, Columns `A`-`M`) and/or hidden -- where you can automatically replicate the values from `Sheet1` that are the basis for the conditional formatting. So cells in `Sheet2` Column ***`D`*** would be conditionally formatted based on formulas referring to cells in `Sheet2` Column ***`Q`*** (which are replicas of cells in `Sheet1`).

Comment: Oh I see now! On the first reading I thought you meant to duplicate in the _same corresponding cell_, not with a marker cell. This works, sorry I was a bit dense.